# Vertices dominating over a particular vertex in the graph

Tags: data-structures, graph

[image]

In the above graph, which vertices dominating over vertex 6?

Comment: Is the entry node 0?

Comment: its not mentioned in the question

Comment: @harold what is meant by dominating over?

Comment: It is important, x dominating n over means that every path from the entry to n must go through x. But perhaps we can assume that 0 is the entry, then 0 and 6 dominate 6.

Comment: will 6 dominate itself?

Comment: it appears to me that 1 and 2 should also be dominating over vertex 6

Comment: Nodes always dominate themselves "non-strictly", 1 and 2 don't dominate 6 because you could go through either 1 or 2, so it is not true that all paths to 6 must go through 1, and neither is it true that all paths must go through 2.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about graph theory outside the context of programming.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo i encountered this question in a qiuz on data structures, so it isrelated to programming

Answer (score 1):

Answer is 0,1,2,3,4,5.
A vertex A is said to be dominating over vertex B, only if there is path from the entry node to B that is going through vertex A. In above question, only vertex 7 cannot lie in the path from any source vertex to destination,that is vertex 6.

Comment: No, that's not it. A node does not dominate node N if it lies on *some* path from the entry to N, only if it lies on *all* paths from the entry to N.

Comment: but this the answer shown in the quiz, where i found this question

Comment: Quizzes can be wrong too, perhaps you should send them a correction